# how to create dynamoDB efficiently with my table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If each of my database's an overview has only two types (state: pending, appended), is it efficient to designate these two types as partition keys? Or is it effective to index this state value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more effective to use a [sparse index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html). In your case, you might add an attribute called `isPending`. You can add this attribute to items that are pending, and remove it once they are appended. If you create a GSI with `tid` as the hash key and `isPending` as the sort key, then only items that are pending will be in the GSI.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It will depend on how would you search for these records!</strike>

<strike>For example, if you will always search by record ID, it never minds. But if you will search every time by the set of records pending, or appended, you should think in use partitions.</strike>

You also could research in this Best practice guide from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html

---

**Updating:**
In this section of [best practice guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach), it recommends the following:

> **Keep related data together.**   Research on routing-table optimization
>   20 years ago found that "locality of reference" was the single most
>   important factor in speeding up response time: keeping related data
>   together in one place. This is equally true in NoSQL systems today,
>   where keeping related data in close proximity has a major impact on
>   cost and performance. Instead of distributing related data items
>   across multiple tables, you should keep related items in your NoSQL
>   system as close together as possible.
>
> As a general rule, you should maintain as few tables as possible in a
>   DynamoDB application. As emphasized earlier, most well designed
>   applications require only one table, unless there is a specific reason
>   for using multiple tables.
>
> Exceptions are cases where high-volume time series data are involved,
>   or datasets that have very different access patterns—but these are
>   exceptions. A single table with inverted indexes can usually enable
>   simple queries to create and retrieve the complex hierarchical data
>   structures required by your application.
>
> **Use sort order.**   Related items can be grouped together and queried
>   efficiently if their key design causes them to sort together. This is
>   an important NoSQL design strategy.
>
> **Distribute queries.**   It is also important that a high volume of
>   queries not be focused on one part of the database, where they can
>   exceed I/O capacity. Instead, you should design data keys to
>   distribute traffic evenly across partitions as much as possible,
>   avoiding "hot spots."
>
> **Use global secondary indexes**.   By creating specific global secondary
>   indexes, you can enable different queries than your main table can
>   support, and that are still fast and relatively inexpensive.

I hope I could help you!

Comment: Thanks for your kindness!!  I'd like to ask you one more question. I will often extract data that is state=PENDING. State said.PENDING or APPROVED. As far as I know, DynamoDB's partition key is divided into groups within the DB. Then, can't we just use the position key as the state instead of giving an index to the state? 
+ In addition, I have to work to change the PENDING state to APPROVED state. If state is a partition key, it cannot be changed, so I want to delete that element and put it back in APPROVED. Do you think this is gonna be okay? Thanks a lot

Comment: I've read the best practice guide and take a look at this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach.

Mainly in the sections 

`Keep related data together`, `Use sort order` and  `Use global secondary indexes.`

It's better to keep it in one table.

Comment: Thanks a lot! love u